# How to create multiline TextBox in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to create multiline TextBox in Xamarin.Forms?

With some research I found that it can be done with `<Editor>` tag in XAML page with custom font size and style but that creates center aligned text. However I want to start cursor and text from top left.

Comment: you should put some or your code, like the Editor and its parent. an Editor without any attributes but a height, is multi-line and not centered by default

Comment: In traditional Xamarin, you can do this just by selecting inputType to textMultiLine in properties.

Answer (score 21):

The Editor is used for collecting text that is expected to take more than one line.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="TextSample.EditorPage"
Title="Editor">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Editor Text="Editor is used for collecting text that is expected to take more than one line." BackgroundColor="#2c3e50" HeightRequest="100" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use an [`Editor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor) as the code below and specifying the maximum number of characters:

```
<Editor Keyboard="Plain" AutoSize="TextChanges" MaxLength="180" />
```

---

Note: Using `AutoSize="TextChanges"` the editor will change the size to accommodate input as the user enters it. Automatic resizing is turned off by default.

Answer (score 6):

The [Editor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Editor/) as you mentioned, coded like this (sample from page) does not create centered text

```
  <StackLayout Padding="5,10">
        <Editor>
            <Editor.BackgroundColor>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Color"
                    iOS="#a4eaff"
                    Android="#2c3e50"
                    WinPhone="#2c3e50" />
            </Editor.BackgroundColor>
        </Editor>
    </StackLayout>
```